# sorting numbers in array of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have an array of string (concatarray) that is contains items such as

`15.234 Mon 10`, `20.12345 Tue 11`, `11.3521 Wed 12`, `1901.23 Thu 13`

and I wish to sort it from largest number to smallest, like this

`1901.23 Thu 13`, `20.12345 Tue 11`, `15.234 Mon 10`, `11.3521 Wed 12`

I tried

> Array.Sort< string > (concatarray);
>
> Array.Reverse(concatarray);

but that gets to

`20.12345 Tue 11`, `1901.23 Thu 13`, `15.234 Mon 10`, `11.3521 Wed 12`

Comment: Are they always in the format `<num>{ }<string>`?

Comment: You will have to separate the number from the  rest of the entry, then you can sort the numbers by comparing them to each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorting the strings will sort them using a text comparison. To sort on the number, you would extract the part of the string that is number and parse it to a `double` value:

```
concatarray =
  concatarray
  .OrderByDescending(i => Double.Parse(i.Split(' ', 2)[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Great answer, but can I ask why you choose double over float?

Comment: @Gray: I actually didn't consider using `float`, but some of the numbers in the example have seven digits of precision, which is right at the limit of what the `float` type can handle. It's plausible that other values in the data have even more digits. The CPU uses `double` internally for all floating point operations, so if you use `float` the values will be converted to `double` whenever they are used, so `double` is a more natural choice for values to work with.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It compiled successfully, but when I ran it, it gave me an error saying `System.Form at Exception: Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: @theGlitch: That means that you have some strings in your data that are not following the format in your example.

Comment: @Guffa I realized what was causing it. It was split by a `_` rather than a space . I fixed it and it worked. Another question, but is there a way to split the double and the date into two arrays?

Comment: @theGlitch: Create the two arrays for the result and loop throught the items and use `.Split(' ', 2)` to get an array that contains the number and the date. Put those in the corresponding items in the result arrays.